# Doesn't Groovy 3.0.8 YamlSlurper support multidoc YAML files?

Tags: groovy, yaml

I haven't found a way to parse multidocs using Groovy 3.0.8's YamlSlurper.

I have tried the following:

```
def multiDocYaml = '''\
---
version: 1
---
version: 2
'''

// For YAML with multiple documents separated by ---
// we first need to remove the separators, otherwise
// only the first document is parsed.
def multiDoc = new YamlSlurper().parseText(multiDocYaml.replaceAll('---', ''))
```

borrowing the example from:

https://blog.jdriven.com/2020/03/groovy-goodness-parse-yaml-with-yamlslurper/

The result is a LazyMap having only one record with `version: 2`.
It should mean the properties are merged into one with the last winning.

Also I've tried without replacing each `---` with empty string and got a LazyMap of one record only having `version: 1`.
I understand it should mean the second YAML doc after `---` is completely ignored by YamlSlurper.

The only way I can parse YAML multidoc files correctly using the YamlSlurper is dividing the files into single YAML doc ones and parsing then.

Answer (score 1):

No, as it says in the blog post you link to, it doesn't

If you can load all the yaml into memory, then you could do something like:

```
def documents = multiDocYaml.split('---').findAll().collect {
    new YamlSlurper().parseText(it)
}

assert documents[0].version == 1
assert documents[1].version == 2
```

Comment: This answer was helpful, but note that the split expression is not specific enough. That will match any sequence of three dashes in the text. It really needs to be "(?m)^---$".